# How to pivot columns correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    NUMBER          NAME
1   000231          John Stockton
2   009456          Karl Malone
3   100000901       John Stockton
4   100008496       Karl Malone
```

I want to obtain a new dataframe with:

```
    NAME            VALUE1  VALUE2
1   John Stockton   000231  100000901
2   Karl Malone     009456  100008496
```

I think I should use `pd.groupby()`, but I have no function to pass as an aggregator (I don't need to compute any `mean()`, `min()`, or `max()` value). If I just use `pd.groupby()` without any aggregator, I get:

```py
In[1]: pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['NAME']))

Out[1]: 
           0               1
        0  John Stockton   NAME NUMBER 000231 100000901
        1  Karl Malone     NAME NUMBER 009456 100008496
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to pivot the dataframe?

Comment: Check Question 10

Comment: @jezrael what do you mean Check Question 10?

Comment: In duplicate answer.

Comment: @jezrael can you post a link to it? I can't see it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: ### df1 = df.groupby('NAME').agg(lambda x: [i for i in x]).reset_index() ### 
df1[['Value1','Value2']] = pd.DataFrame(df1.NUMBER.tolist()) ### 
df1.drop('NUMBER',axis=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need a bit mode complicated pipeline:

```
(df.assign(group=df.groupby('NAME').cumcount().add(1)
   .pivot(index='NAME', columns='group', values='NUMBER')
   .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
   .add_prefix('VALUE')
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
            NAME  VALUE1     VALUE2
0  John Stockton     231  100000901
1    Karl Malone    9456  100008496
```

Comment: Better is cumcount

Comment: @jezrael yes, I was actually changing it ;) thanks!

Comment: But it is dupe, question 10

Comment: what means "question 10"?

Comment: in duplicate Q/A

Comment: I see, honestly here I think a separate answer is better, huge Q/A like the one you linked to are very difficult to read though

Comment: Exactly it is reason why add to comments check question 10